# Delete a file in sharepoint using Azure Data Factory Delete Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to delete a file that is located in a sharepoint directory after successful copy activity. The Delete Activity is having the following properties:

```
 Linked Service : HTTP
 DataSet : Excel
 Additional Header: @{concat('Authorization: Bearer ',activity('GetToken').output.access_token)} 
                             Here, GetToken is the Web Activity in ADF that generates a token number for accessing SharePoint.
```

When I am running the pipeline, I am getting the below error:

```
  Invalid delete activity payload with 'folderPath' that is required and cannot be empty.
```

I have no clue on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are trying to delete a file in Sharepoint online using Azure Data Factory.

> Currently delete activity in ADF only supports the below data stores and not sharepoint online. which is why you are receiving the above error.

- Azure Blob storage
- Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1
- Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2
- Azure Files
- File System
- FTP
- SFTP
- Amazon S3
- Amazon S3 Compatible Storage
- Google Cloud Storage
- Oracle Cloud Storage
- HDFS

> Image: [Delete activity Supported Data stores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks7oc.png)

> Ref: [Delete activity supported data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/delete-activity#supported-data-stores)

As a workaround you may try exploring [HTTP connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http?tabs=data-factory). OR you can use [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity) and write your own code to delete files from SharePoint.

Hope this info helps.

Comment: I am using HTTP Connector only.